# Issue while setting up local HPCC cluster using WSL

Tags: hpcc, hpcc-ecl

When I start the cluster ( using the command *etc/init.d/hpcc-init start*). Starting mydali shows a TIMEOUT message. Something like this:
[image: Terminal Image]

How do I solve this problem?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

TIMEOUT means that the underlying process (dali) was able to start but wasn't able to write-out its sentinel file. The sentinel file write-out is generally the last step in each processes setup logic. This means the problem is likely some resource dali was trying to access that it couldn't find, or didn't have permissions to access. To figure out exactly why there is an issue we need to go into the log files for that specific process (dali). Those logs should be located at /var/log/HPCCSystems/mydali/server. Find the log with the date stamp pertaining to when the issue occurred and you should see a line that says "Build community_-1". That line is the first line output at startup. Read after that line and you should get a clue to what the underlying problem is.